# Medrashim which seem to go against logic

Tags: talmud-gemara, midrash, agada-stories-legends

I am giving a speech this week. I would like to include examples of Medrashim which seem implausible that it ever happened or could have ever happened.

Can any of you provide examples of medrashim that would go against logic **Please provide a source**

Can we get as many answers as we can!

Thanks

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org/Yevamot.63a.12
https://www.sefaria.org/Taanit.25a.13
https://www.sefaria.org/Moed_Katan.16b.22

Comment: I feel this is gonna to get closed because it might be opinion-based. Maybe you could rephrase your question if possible?

Comment: Thanks. Hopefully that is better

Comment: @fulltimekollelguy what's the title of the speech?

Comment: Good questions vs Bad questions- based on the Maharan 64, is there a use of sweeping Hashkavah questions the bother us under the rug or should the be discussed? I want to give an example of a medrash that would bother most people in making sense, yet many people pretend that it makes sense- the point is if it bothers you and your point is to become closer to Hashem by trying to understand his Torah, its a good question

Comment: @fulltimekollelguy Better.

Comment: @Shmuel thank you, you are a big tzaddik!

Comment: Aggadot Rabbah bar bar Chanah come to mind.

Comment: I tried to get chatgpt to provide some. Just gave examples of Hashem creating something with this letter and destroying something with that letter.

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/4037/ https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/53349/ https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/13003/ https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/17249 https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/76804/ https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/51377/ See also: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/53545

Comment: More to your question, perhaps you would be interested in the examples in the following posts: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/18567/ https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/26552/ https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/29195/ https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/14641/ https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/893/ https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/38410/